# Is there a brief tutorial of customizing a basic and simple chromium browser

Tags: chromium

I would like to customize a simple browser based on chromium.

I hope it has some great features -

**1.A default custmized page will be loaded after the browser lanuchs up.**

**2.Highly customized right click menus.**

**3.Disable some regular areas like Menu Bar, Tool Bar, Address Bar.**

**4.Disable developer tool mode.**

I don't know whether these features need to do some deep coding or just some configruation of code before compile it.

Great appreciate if someone point me out.
A tutorial will be better.

The chromium is great but also huge for me.

Thanks again!

Comment: 1 can be done by new tab page extension, not sure about 2 but for 3 and 4, you will have to modify the source code

Comment: Thank you so much! @Asesh
Could you please give me more detail of how-to-do-it?